# Ruby on Rails, URL modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I want to make a "hacker news" clone in Ruby on Rails, and I am stuck working on URLs.

How do I show the main URL not the extension?

For example, instead of:

```
www.somewebsite.com/someurlextension
```

I want to show:

```
www.somewebsite.com.
```

How do I convert it?

Comment: does `/someurlextension` call a controller & action?

Comment: You show us what you've written to try to solve the problem, and then explain why it's not accomplishing what you want to do. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information on how to create a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URI to get the "host" of a URL:

`url_host = URI.parse( 'http://www.somewebsite.com/someurlextension' ).host`

Comment: thanks for the reply. But where I gonna use it, in controller?

Comment: I assume you want to want to display this somewhere in your view, so keeping this logic in a helper method wouldn't be inappropriate. If you're asking this question though, I would highly recommend taking a break from this project to do a more general overview of Rails - perhaps with something like [Michael Hartl's tutorial, free to read online](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). Once you have a broad overview of Rails, I promise you'll be way, way more productive when building your own applications.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will follow it.